# Use doxygen file header as module description

Tags: c, documentation, grouping, doxygen

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to reuse the doxygen file header description also for the module description.

```
/**
   \file               
   \brief         Some brief info
   \details       more Details
*/
/**
   \defgroup Views
   \brief (Same as header doxy)
   \details (Same as header doxy)
*/
```

To avoid redundancy I will not copy the text. If I move the defgroup to top of the file I only get the file name mentioned in the module not the description. I tried already some combinations but I never achieved my goal. The detail and brief Text is either in the module documentation or in the file documentation. Does anyone have another idea how to reuse the text?

Many Thanks,

Jonny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself.
You can use the doxy command @copydoc to copy the documentation.

My code for test.h looks the following:

```
/**
   \file          test.h
   \brief         Some brief info
   \details       more Details
*/
/**
   \defgroup Views
   @copydoc view.h
*/
```